# Adding a piechart element to a panel created in build com.intellij.uiDesigner

Tags: java

I have created frame with panels in IntelliJ IDEA UI designer, but when I wanted to add a Pie chart it returned an error.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.getRow()" because "c" is null
    at com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridLayoutManager.addLayoutComponent(GridLayoutManager.java:134)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1156)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:493)
    at org.homemade.stockmanager.GuiStockLogic.initGeneralShareInfo(GuiStockLogic.java:447)
    at org.homemade.stockmanager.GuiStockLogic.updateStockTable(GuiStockLogic.java:257)
    at org.homemade.stockmanager.GuiStockLogic.showStockTable(GuiStockLogic.java:166)
    at org.homemade.stockmanager.GuiStockLogic.init(GuiStockLogic.java:264)
    at org.homemade.main.MainGuiLogic.lambda$init$1(MainGuiLogic.java:50)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2313)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
```

Here is my implementation:

```
    DefaultPieDataset dataset = new DefaultPieDataset();
    dataset.setValue("Category 1", 20);
    dataset.setValue("Category 2", 30);
    dataset.setValue("Category 3", 50);
    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart("Pie Chart", dataset, true, true, false);
    ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
    chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(400, 300));
    pieChartPanel.add(chartPanel,0);
```

Comment: What makes you think that the problem is to do with the pie chart? Your stack trace is arising from a button click. In fact it is ultimately undesirable to use gui builders as they produce unmaintainable black box code which is also fragile. Better to learn to use layout managers

Comment: I am not sure if this is related with button click. What I know is that after I added the chart panel  ( chartPanel) to a panel (pieChartPanel) created in GUI got this error. I am sure I am missing some configuration  before adding it, but I don't know what.

Comment: Issue solved by using and adding maven dependency: 
```
    <dependency>             
        <groupId>com.intellij</groupId>             
        <artifactId>forms_rt</artifactId>             
        <version>7.0.3</version>         
    </dependency> 
```
And changing this code line: 

`pieChartPanel.add(chartPanel,new GridConstraints());`